# Typescript can't access JSON object (Angular2)

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular

I have the weirdest problem.

I'm receiving a JSON object

```
{"login":"admin","name":"Admin"}
```

And what I'm doing in code is:

```
private _userData: User;
...
private getUserData() {
    this._userInfoService.getUserInfo()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this._userData = data.json(); // (using <User> data.json() changes nothing
            },
            err => alert(err)
        );
}
```

Where User type is

```
export interface User {
    login: string;
    name: string;
}
```

But when I'm trying to access those fields in html with angular:

```
<p>{{ _userData.login }}</p>
<p>{{ _userData.name }}</p>
```

I'm getting some nasty errors in console like:
`Error: EXCEPTION: TypeError: l__userData21 is null in [{{ _userData.login }} in UserHomeComponent@8:7]`

although I can clearly see when I'm doing console.log on this object:
`Object { login: "admin", name: "Admin" }`

I did it exactly the same with other class and it works there. What is even more interesting is that when I slightly change the code, like this:

```
private _name: string;
private _login: string;
...
private getUserData() {
    this._userInfoService.getUserInfo()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this._name = (<User> data.json()).name;
                this._login = (<User> data.json()).login;
            },
            err => alert(err)
        );
}
```

and view:

```
<p>{{ _login }}</p>
<p>{{ _name }}</p>
```

Then everything works perfectly! I have absolutely no clue what is happening (tried to cast data.json() to  but that changes nothing.)

@Edit:
The other class, where it works is:

```
export interface LoginData {
    access_token: string;
    token_type: string;
    refresh_token: string;
    expires_in: number;
    scope: string;
}


private _loginData = <LoginData> JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("loginData")); //tried this also with User, doesn't work
```

and in the view:

```
<p>access_token: {{ _loginData.access_token }}</p>
<p>token_type: {{ _loginData.token_type }}</p>
<p>refresh_token: {{ _loginData.refresh_token }}</p>
<p>expires_in: {{ _loginData.expires_in }}</p>
```

Comment: where does this `.json()` function come from? I know you tried `JSON.parse()`, but still...

Answer (score 10):

the user data comes in asynchronously which means that it is **undefined** before.
this is when angular will throw an exception because you do **undefined**.login

what you will have to do is to indicate that userData may be undefined by using the elvis-operator.

try this:

```
<p>{{ _userData?.login }}</p>
<p>{{ _userData?.name }}</p>
```

alternatively you can use a wrapping *ngIf for example

btw this has nothing to do with typescript, but with angular2 and javascript. please edit your title properly

Answer (score 0):

You try to establish a databinding to `_userData.login` and NOT to `_userData`

I see two possible errors:

First:
- As Patrick already wrote, you data arrives asynchronously, which means `_userData.login` is undefined when you try to establish the data-binding, because `_userData` is undefined (and has no default null value). Therefore the data-binding **fails** and you won't be informed / get any updates when you *later* update it
- Your second example works, how ever, because `_name` and `_login` are not undefined but filled with their `NULL` value (I guess an empty string). Because of that the data binding is actually successfully estasblished

Second:
- Second possible error is a binding of object references and object attributes.
- Depending on how the change listener are implemented it is actually a difference between `obj1 = newObject` and `obj1.attr1 = newValue`. So changing just the object itself wouldn't trigger the change listener on a single attribute.

How ever, I'd bet it's the first possibility. You could test this by initializing the `User` object with an empty object in the constructor...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this in front of the `<p>` tags:

```
<div *ngFor="let uData of _userDat;">
```

and then

```
<p>{{uData.login}} 
</p></div>
```

OR

```
<div *ngIf="user">
<p>{{_userDat.login}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **?** for safe navigation.

```
<p>{{ _userData?.login }}</p>
```